# Codeigniter session was not stored in database when using database driver

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Codeigniter session was not stored in database when using database driver on live server. But it's working fine local enviroment.

Codeigniter Version : 3.1.9
PHP Version : 7.2.11

Below my codeigniter configuration,

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 600;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 180;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Anyone have idea, please advise.

Comment: Ok obvious question time... Did you change the database settings to match the live server and that the database exists and all that kind of stuff?

Comment: I'm using below database config,

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);

Comment: I was talking about /application/config/database.php - have you checked the settings in that file for the database... Although you would think it would create a connect error message. Check your error logs and what not... something is not as it seems...

Comment: I don't see any error logs.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Database connectivity also good. Why i'm sure in connectivity, I'm able to save everything in database using my application. But session only not stored in our database. I'm also tried ci_session table with manual entry that's also good. But my investigation i found, Session_database_driver.php file not triggered when i click or refresh any page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you got to change the configs to use database like this:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Then you have to create a table for your sessions and i've create a migration file for this:

```
class Migration_Create_ci_sessions extends CI_Migration
{    
    private $table;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->dbforge();
        $this->table = 'ci_sessions';
    }

    public function up()
    {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table($this->table, TRUE);

        $ci_sessions = '`id` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` BLOB NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)';

        $this->dbforge->add_field($ci_sessions);
        unset($ci_sessions);

        $this->dbforge->create_table($this->table, TRUE);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table($this->table, TRUE);
    }
}
```

or if you prefer you can use sql directly:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

and of course you have to load or autoload your database:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

and set the configs for database correctly:

```
'username' => 'username',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'database',
```

Comment: I'm already configured the config.php file as a same what you send. Can you confirm we need to set a sess_cookie_name same as sess_save_path.

Comment: Nope they don't have to be the same name, and if everything above done right can you confirm that the connectivity with database is ok and functional? cause if it is not ok so for sure its a different issue!

Comment: Database connectivity also good. Why i'm sure in connectivity, I'm able to save everything in database using my application. But session only not stored in our database. I'm also tried ci_session table with manual entry that's also good. But my investigation i found, Session_database_driver.php file not triggered when i click or refresh any page.

Comment: And are you sure that the session library is loaded? can you confirm?

Comment: yeah, it's loaded. I verified in log.
INFO ---> Database Driver Class Initialized
INFO ---> Session: Class initialized using 'database' driver.

Comment: sorry for the double check, what is the output of this `var_dump($this->load->is_loaded('session'));`?

Comment: Result : string(7) "session"
FYI : issue occur only in server. not in my local. local working fine

Comment: Then everything is ok with your application, so my guess would be server configuration problem. but lets try one more and a messy solution .. put `session_start();` in your `index.php` and try again!

Comment: Btw have you set your `$config['cookie_domain']` in you `config.php`?

Comment: Not the `sess_cookie_name` i meant the `cookie_domain`?

Comment: oops, no. I'm not set a cookie domain

Comment: No, Still issue persist. Can i need to set a cookie domain? FYI In our server we are not using codeigniter cookie "ci_sessions". Currently we are using load balanced server generated cookie. Do you have Any idea about ALB Cookie?

Comment: As we said its a server configuration issue and i don't know anything about your server and its configuration so you might want to ask a different question that sessions not working in your server